# Query optimizer slows down my queries

Tags: h2

When using the stable 1.3.176 my query, which has 7 tables to join returns pretty fast.
After upgrading to the 1.4.191 I see my query returning in 20 to 40 times longer.

This came from the Optimizer which decided that even for 7 joins all plans should be tested using brute force.  These setting are unfortunately not configurable.
I played a bit making them configurable and that made my query return in a decent time again.

Are there plans to making these brute force and genetic settings of the Optimizer configurable?

Comment: Are you aware that 1.4 is still considered beta?

Comment: "Are there plans to making these brute force and genetic settings of the Optimizer configurable?" Only the developers of H2 can answer this.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it is still beta, but I need the 1.4 to get the concurrent access which was not working on the 1.3.  I was hoping the H2 developers would indeed answer me on this one.

Comment: Why no ask the developers directly: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/h2-database

Comment: Ok, thanx .. I will do that right now.